# How to go to previous state onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
else if(id == R.id.courses)
    {
```

> What should I write here to go to the previous state on back pressed?

```
        setContentView(R.layout.our_courses);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, but this above makes no sense for us. please show us the meaning and explain a little bit more. Is this the code you wrote in onBackPressed()?

Answer (score 0):

You would handle the code separately under its own overriden method, onBackPressed(). For instance:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    switchToFragment(mMainMenuFragment);
}
```